# The value in the INPUT field cannot store in state of React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I trying to get the user input value from the INPUT field and update in the corresponding state. But what I type in the field it did not set to the state

```
creatForm(x){
    var dx = 'd'+x  
    let day = 'DAY'+x
    return this.state[dx].map((el,i)=>
        <div key={i}>
            <Form>
                <Form.Group inline>
                    <Form.Field>
                    <label><h4>{day}</h4></label>
                        <Input name='startTime' value={el.startTime ||''} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this,i,dx)}/>
                    </Form.Field>
                    <Form.Field>
                        <Input name='endTime' value={el.endTime ||''} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this,i,dx)}/>
                    </Form.Field>
                    <Form.Field>
                        <Input name='location' value={el.location ||''} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this,i,dx)}/>
                        <Button icon='plus' inverted color='blue' onClick={this.addClick}/>

                        {this.showMinus(i)}
                    </Form.Field>
                </Form.Group>
            </Form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

```
handleChange(i,dx, e) {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    let d = [...this.state[dx]];
    d[i] = {...d[i], [name]: value};
    console.log(d[i])
    this.setState({ d });
}
```

```
this.state={
    d1:[{startTime:'',
         endTime:'',
         location:''}],
    d2:[{startTime:'',
         endTime:'',
         location:''}],
    d3:[{startTime:'',
         endTime:'',
         location:''}]
}
```

Any error of my **handleChange** function?

Comment: The log `console.log(d[i])` is working as expected or not?. And please tell that is `i` and `dx`

Comment: If I type 'hello', the `console.log(d[i])` will show like `{startTime: "h", endTime: "", location: ""}`, and overwrite by `{startTime: "e", endTime: "", location: ""}` and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `this.setState({ d });` Will change the property `d` of the state which is not present.
You can add `dx` after `d` and use Computed Property Names

```
handleChange(i,dx, e) {
    const { name, value } = e.target;        
    let d = [...this.state[dx]];
    d[i] = {...d[i], [name]: value};
    console.log(d[i])
    this.setState({ [dx]:d });
}
```

Comment: If I using `this.setState({ [d+dx]:d })` it face same problem. After I change to `this.setState({ [dx]:d });` then it work properly

Comment: @WenhaoHong  Sorry I didn't knew about the context of your data. I gave the basic idea. Glad to know it worked I also edited the post